# Angularjs directive to make any element work like a link

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink

I tried to write a directive making an arbitrary element work like a link. Something like

```
<span goto="overview">Overview</span>
```

to be translated into something like

```
<span ng-click="$location.path('#/overview')">Overview</span>
```

or whatever will work. As a bonus I'd like the link to work, even when the current URL is already `.../#overview`.<sup>1</sup>

This sound pretty trivial, but I'm stuck with something like

```
.directive('goto', function($location) {
    return {
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            // Here `attrs` should be used but how?
            var ref = "#/" + element.attr('goto');

            // This is a mystery to me.
            // I guess, transclusion is the way to go, but how exactly?
            var elementContent = getEverythingBelowElementButHow();

            // I doubt `$location` will be visible on the invocation site.
            return "<span ng-click='$location.path(" +
                ref + "'>" +
                elementContent +
                "</span>";
        }
    };
})
```

I'm perfectly sure, I'm doing it all wrong. I'm nearly sure it's all unnecessary complicated. However, I'm hoping to be able to learn something from the answers.

---

<sup>1</sup>I found myself repeatedly clicking on such a link in order to get to the "pristine overview state" and wondering that nothing happens. Obviously, the browser ignores links to the current location, but there could be a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
app.directive('goto', function($location){
  function link(scope, element, attr){
    scope.gotoLink = function(){
      alert(scope.goto);
      //$location.path(scope.goto);
    };
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope:{ goto: '@' },
    template: '<span ng-click="gotoLink()"><span ng-transclude></span></span>',
    link: link
  };
});
```

You can play with it [here (plnkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vxg5jLgpBaK5hCCFoZQA?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect. A side question: I see that using `@` in the scope is better, but I'm curious how to work with `attr` in the `link` function? I tried `attr.goto` and looked at it in debugger, but I can't see there anything usable.

Answer (score 3):

You can add click event to directive dynamically.

```
angular.module('ExApp')
 .directive('goto', function($location) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       //scope variables            
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attr) {
       element.on('click', function() {
         $location.path('/overview');
         scope.$apply();
       });
     }
   }
 });
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/n6VbZnAVzM4y0p8dbmvf?p=preview